# Approach to make a one line script into a one line command?

Tags: ruby

Below is my "one liner" in a script.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

puts ARGF.read.gsub(/\\caption\{((?:[^{}]+|\{\g<1>\})+)\}/m) { |xx, yy|
  Regexp.last_match[0].gsub(/([^\\])#/,'\1\\#') }
```

If I just insert in `ruby -pe ''` I get

```
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting ')'
...ast_match[0].gsub(/([^\\])#/,1\#) }
...                               ^
```

With double quotes I get

```
-e:1: premature end of char-class: /([^\])#/
```

**Question**

So the question is what is the approach to make it work in `ruby -pe ''`?

Comment: It contains single quotes, so when you embed it in single quotes on the command line, you need to escape the inner single quotes. Or use an alternate quoting mechanism

Comment: I just tried and updated OP with the error.

Comment: @mudasobwa You are correct, comment updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `%q||` instead of single quotes in your one-liner, it’s effectively the same but it won’t mess up with command line single quotes:

```
puts ARGF.read.gsub(RE1) { Regexp.last_match[0].gsub(/([^\\])#/,%q|\1\\#|) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but the standard way to escape strings to be used in a shell is something like this:

```
require "shellwords"

`some_command #{Shellwords.escape(some_command_written_in_ruby_string)}`
```